# problem with registration and login php,will you check my code?if there is an error

Tags: php, arrays, authentication, registration

I have a problem with either registration and login shows (undefined offset) and look at registration is there some problem with my code?it is the registration form the problem it sometimes saves the existing email in spite of the fact that I wrote a function for not submitting the existing email which is inside my `data.txt`. shortly the functions do not work properly

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_reg'])){
    $var=file("data.txt");
    $userData = $_POST['email'] . " " . $_POST['password'] . "\r\n";
    $lines=0;
        $db = fopen("data.txt", "a+");
        foreach($var as $key=>$value){
            $user = (explode(' ', $value));
            if ($_POST["password"] === $_POST["confirm_password"]) {
                    //print_r($value);
                if (trim($user[0]) == $_POST['email']) {
                    $lines++;
                }
                break;

            } 
        }
            if($lines){
                    echo "The email is already exists ";
                }else{
                 fwrite($db,$userData."\r\n");
                 fclose($db);
                 echo "you are registered successfully ";
              }
} 
?>
```

and it is my login form the problem with login is it gives an error undefined offset 12

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_log'])) {
    $email =isset($_POST['email']);
    $password =isset($_POST['password']);
    $file = explode( PHP_EOL, file_get_contents( "data.txt" ));
    $auth = false;
 foreach( $file as $line ) {
    list($email, $password) = explode(" ", $line);

    if ($_POST['email'] == $email && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
        $auth =true;
        break; 
    }
}
        if($auth) {
            echo "Login successfull!";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid username or password";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: While I don't really agree with storing plaintext passwords in a txt file, there are several places you could improve your code.  For the actual error my guess (without the line numbers) is that you probably have an extra line return at the end of the file.  Which results in the last item being something like `$line = ['']`

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plaintext, not anywhere or ever!** I would also recommend using a database rather than a textfile if you expect there to be many users.

Answer (score 1):

Let me say first off, storing plaintext passwords in a `.txt` file is probably not the best way of building a longin system. (that's the disclaimer anyway).

**Undefined offset (just a guess)**

That said I see a few places to improve your code.  My guess without more specifics about the error, is you may be pulling a empty array at the end of the file, it's typical to leave a hanging line return at the end (a new line with nothing else for the last line).  Which may turn into something like this once you explode it for the second time on the space `['']`.  And then you try to access it using `list` which gives you undefined offsets.

You could use `array_filter` and maybe trim but instead of doing this:

```
 $file = explode( PHP_EOL, file_get_contents( "data.txt" ));
```

You could try (which you should know as you use this function already)

```
 $file = file( "data.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ));
```

The file function, takes a file and breaks it into an array based on the line returns.  So this takes the place of both explode and file_get_contents.

Then it has 2 (bitwise) flags which you could make use of:

> array **file** ( string **$filename** [, int **$flags** = 0 [, resource **$context** ]] )
>
> Reads an entire file into an array.
>
> **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES**
>
> Omit newline at the end of each array element
>
> **FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES**
>
> Skip empty lines

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

These take the place of filtering the data for empty lines (something you weren't doing).  Granted this is a file you created but you never know when a errant line return could creep in there.

**Non-unique entries**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_reg'])){
    $var=file("data.txt");
    $userData = $_POST['email'] . " " . $_POST['password'] . "\r\n";
    $lines=0;
    $db = fopen("data.txt", "a+");
    foreach($var as $key=>$value){
        $user = (explode(' ', $value));
        if ($_POST["password"] === $_POST["confirm_password"]) {
   //NOTE: the uniqueness check only happens when the confirm password matches
            if (trim($user[0]) == $_POST['email']) {
                $lines++;
            }
            break;

        } 
    }
    if($lines){
        echo "The email is already exists ";
    }else{
  //NOTE:yet you save it no matter if that is the case
        fwrite($db,$userData."\r\n");
        fclose($db);
        echo "you are registered successfully ";
    }
}
```

Your uniqueness check only works when the confirm password matches the password, however when it comes time to save the data, there is no check.  Instead of just adding that check in around the saving bit, it would be better to wrap the whole thing inside this confirm test, as both pieces of that are known before touching the file:

Here I reworked this a bit for you

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_reg'])){
    if ($_POST["password"] === $_POST["confirm_password"]) {

        //VERIFY AND SANITIZE user input, if you put junk in you get junk out
        
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
         //again use something better then die
        if(empty($password))die('Password cannot be empty'); 
         //because you split on space, you cannot allow it in inputs
        if(preg_match('/\s+/', $password)) die('Password cannot contain spaces'); 

        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        if(empty($email))die('Email cannot be empty'); 
        //you may want to validate using something better
        if(preg_match('/\s+/', $email )) die('Email cannot contain spaces'); 

        //Use the flags
        $var=file("data.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

        //for duplication we only care if there is 1 previous entry
        //which is enough to say its a duplicate
        $exists=false;

        foreach($var as $key=>$value){
            $user = explode(' ', $value);
            if (trim($user[0]) == $email) {
                //we found a match this is enough to call it a duplicate
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }
            
        }
        
        if($exists){
            echo "The email is already exists ";
        }else{
            file_put_contants("data.txt", $email." ".$password.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            echo "you are registered successfully ";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Confirm password must match password";
    }
}
```

**Other stuff**

These are also incorrect:

```
$email =isset($_POST['email']);
$password =isset($_POST['password']);
```

Isset returns a boolean value, so you are assigning `true` or `false` to those two variables. This doesn't matter as you never check them and in your loop you  overwrite with the call to `list()`.  But just because someting "doesn't matter" doesn't mean it's correct.

These really should be something like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['email'])) 
    die("no email"); //dont use die but do some kind of error message

if(isset($_POST['password']))
    die("no password"); //dont use die but do some kind of error message
```

**SUMMERY**

Really it's quite a mess. What I mean by this is you used 3 different ways to open and access the file data. You used the PHP line constant in some places but not all. You had code that was somewhat haphazardly thrown around, where you were setting things long before you need them, and in some cases you may not have needed them, so you were wasting resources setting them.

Please don't take the criticism hard, as I am not trying to offend.  Simply pointing out places you could improve the flow of the code and simplify things.  The big thing is don't get discouraged, in order to program effectively you have to have a no-quite attitude and the drive for continuous self improvement.  Even after 9 years of PHP programing I still learn new things all the time, I learned (and wrote a library around it) something new just 2 days ago...

As I said at the beginning and to be honest a database would actually reduce the amount of code you need.  It might be intimidating at first to use a database but you'll find that it's easier then doing this.  An example is your check for uniqueness, you can set a field to be unique in the Database then you never need to worry about duplicates, only catching the errors for them.

I would suggest looking into `PDO` and prepared statements, `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

A final word of warning is I didn't test any of this so forgive me if there are any typos...

Hope it helps.